# i get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, windows, thonny

What is this error I'm getting? I've been practicing with `Thonny` for quite a while now and fixed many errors by myself but idk about this one can someone pls help me figure out on that I did wrong? The text string where the error happened is the following:

```
print(f"{tafel} x {x} = {(tafel*x)}")
```

Comment: It sounds like `tefel` references `None`. What was the last assignment to `tafel` before this `print()`?

Comment: Impossible to help if you dont post more code.